# URI parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, parameter-passing

I am trying to fetch data from a SQL Server database using an API where I pass two dates as parameters to filter the data, but every time I do it, it throws an exception.

This is my get function:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server =PC-UXYTHBB; database=TEST; User ID=sa;Password=pwdpwd");

    // GET api/values 
    public String Get(string d1, string d2)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEE] where [birthdate] BETWEEN  @d1 and @d2  ", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            return "No data found !!";
        }
}
```

This is the route config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception it throws? Add the exception details to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't send the parameters to the query.
You should write code like this

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[EMPLOYEE] where [birthdate] BETWEEN @d1 and @d2", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1",Convert.ToDateTime(d1));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2",Convert.ToDateTime(d2));
```